# Firefox does not open select box

Tags: firefox

I have this weird problem that Firefox does not open a perfectly normal select box (see [code below](http://jsbin.com/equtu/)). I've already tried to disable all the plugins, themes etc, but still it won't open them. Is there probably some strange setting that causes this?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option value="0">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
      <option value="1">bbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
      <option value="2">cccccccccccc</option>
      <option value="3">dddddddddddd</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any other sites that are giving you trouble? Which OS and which Firefox? (The above http://jsbin.com/equtu/ works fine in Firefox 3.6 on Mac OS X.)

Comment: Works fine here as well FF3.6 W7

Comment: works fine here, firefox 3.5.7, archlinux

Comment: And works fine in 3.6 on Win XP

Comment: I have the same issue and no solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case this is caused by an extension or by something odd in your profile: try running firefox without any extensions, and with a fresh (empty) profile:

```
firefox -safe-mode -P new_profile_name
```

and see if you can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Firefox doesn't like select boxes not in a form. Put  tags around your select box.

Comment: sorry - meant "put FORM tags around..."

Comment: you are able to edit your own answers :)