# Firefox 18 does not open select box

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, html, jquery

I'm using Firefox 18 under Windows XP SP3 to open a page I built using jQuery and jQuery UI to generate a form with 'select boxes'. The select boxes are not being opened. The log has no error messages, only CSS warnings (-moz-border-radius, background properties and so on).

I tried starting Firefox in Safe Mode with a new profile, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/103765/firefox-does-not-open-select-box) but this did not solve the problem.

How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Are these standard HTML select elements or jQuery UI plugins of some sort? Is your code ok; as in, does it work in another browser? Did you try restarting FF with add-ons disabled? How about an uninstall and reinstall (ensuring that any remnants are cleaned in between)?

Comment: These are standard HTML select elements, generated by jQuery. The code is ok, other browsers working fine. I don't use any kind of add-ons on Firefox. I was tryed it on other computers too, same result.